# TF2 Server Error: memory could not be read

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, server-administration

**Environment**:

- Team Fortress 2 dedicated server, latest version
- OS: Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 2.80 GHz
- CPU Usage by TF2 Server: 20-50%
- RAM: 4 GB
- RAM Usage by TF2 Server: ~450 MB
- 17 bots, 1 human playing a LAN game

**Problem**:

When a map finishes, and the server attempts to automatically load the next map, an application error is displayed like:

[image]

The server log files do not indicate any problems.

**server.cfg**:

```
// General Settings //

// Hostname for server.
hostname "My Server"

// Password to play on server.
sv_password "My P@$$w0rd"

// Overrides the max players reported to prospective clients
sv_visiblemaxplayers 24

// Maximum number of rounds to play before server changes maps
mp_maxrounds 5

// Set to lock per-frame time elapse
host_framerate 0

// Set the pause state of the server
setpause 0

// Control where the client gets content from 
// 0 = anywhere, 1 = anywhere listed in white list, 2 = steam official content only
sv_pure 2

// Is the server pausable
sv_pausable 0

// Type of server 0=internet 1=lan
sv_lan 1

// Collect CPU usage stats
sv_stats 1



// Execute Banned Users //
exec banned_user.cfg
exec banned_ip.cfg
writeid
writeip



// Contact & Region //

// Contact email for server sysop
//sv_contact emailaddy@google.com

// The region of the world to report this server in.
// -1 is the world, 0 is USA east coast, 1 is USA west coast
// 2 south america, 3 europe, 4 asia, 5 australia, 6 middle east, 7 africa
sv_region -1



// Rcon Settings //

// Password for rcon authentication (Remote CONtrol)
rcon_password My_Password!

// Number of minutes to ban users who fail rcon authentication
sv_rcon_banpenalty 1440

// Max number of times a user can fail rcon authentication before being banned
sv_rcon_maxfailures 5



// Log Settings //

// Enables logging to file, console, and udp < on | off >.
log on

// Log server information to only one file.
sv_log_onefile 0

// Log server information in the log file.
sv_logfile 1

// Log server bans in the server logs.
sv_logbans 1

// Echo log information to the console.
sv_logecho 1



// Rate Settings //

// Frame rate limiter
fps_max 600

// Min bandwidth rate allowed on server, 0 == unlimited
sv_minrate 0

// Max bandwidth rate allowed on server, 0 == unlimited
sv_maxrate 20000

// Minimum updates per second that the server will allow
sv_minupdaterate 10

// Maximum updates per second that the server will allow
sv_maxupdaterate 66



// Download Settings //

// Allow clients to upload customizations files
sv_allowupload 0

// Allow clients to download files
sv_allowdownload 1

// Maximum allowed file size for uploading in MB
net_maxfilesize 15



// Team Balancing //

// Enable team balancing
mp_autoteambalance 0

// Steam said these two commands are unknown. So I commented them.

// Time after the teams become unbalanced to attempt to switch players.
//mp_autoteambalance_delay 60

// Time after the teams become unbalanced to print a balance warning
//mp_autoteambalance_warning_delay 30

// Teams are unbalanced when one team has this many more players than the other team. (0 disables check)
mp_teams_unbalance_limit 1



// Round and Game Times //

// Game time per map in minutes
mp_timelimit 3

// Enable timers to wait between rounds. WARNING: Setting this to 0 has been known to cause a bug with setup times lasting 5:20 (5 minutes 20 seconds) on some servers!
mp_enableroundwaittime 1

// Time after round win until round restarts
mp_bonusroundtime 8

// If non-zero, the current round will restart in the specified number of seconds
mp_restartround 0

// Enable sudden death
mp_stalemate_enable 1

// Timelimit (in seconds) of the stalemate round.
mp_stalemate_timelimit 300



// Bots //

// Number of computer-controlled bots in the server. If a player is in the server, it will override a bot slot.
tf_bot_quota 17



// Client CVars //

// 0 = enable, 1 = disable respawn times
mp_disable_respawn_times 1

// Restricts spectator modes for dead players
mp_forcecamera 0

// Toggles whether the server allows spectator mode or not
mp_allowspectators 1

// Toggles footstep sounds
mp_footsteps 1

// Toggles game cheats
sv_cheats 0

// After this many seconds without a message from a client, the client is dropped
sv_timeout 900

// Maximum time a player is allowed to be idle (in minutes), made this and sv_timeout equal same time?
mp_idlemaxtime 15

// Deals with idle players 1=send to spectator 2=kick
mp_idledealmethod 2

// Time (seconds) between decal sprays
decalfrequency 30



// Communications //

// enable voice communications
sv_voiceenable 1

// Players can hear all other players, no team restrictions 0=off 1=on
sv_alltalk 0

// Amount of time players can chat after the game is over
mp_chattime 10

// Enable party mode
tf_birthday 0
```

**mapcycle.txt:**

```
koth_sawmill
cp_dustbowl
koth_nucleus
ctf_turbine
koth_badlands
cp_manor_event
koth_lakeside_final
cp_foundry
koth_viaduct
cp_granary
pl_badwater
koth_king
cp_badlands
pl_goldrush
koth_probed
cp_vanguard
pl_swiftwater_final1
koth_moonshine_event
cp_gullywash_final1
pl_hoodoo_final
koth_lazarus
cp_snakewater_final1
pl_thundermountain
koth_lakeside_event
cp_process_final
pl_upward
koth_brazil
cp_metalworks
pl_barnblitz
koth_viaduct_event
cp_gorge
pl_enclosure_final
koth_slasher
cp_sunshine
pl_fifthcurve_event
koth_slaughter_event
cp_mercenarypark
pl_rumble_event
cp_mossrock
pl_precipice_event_final
cp_gorge_event
```

**Update #1**: I thought it might be the outdated OS (Windows XP) so I installed Windows 10 instead and guess what... the server completely shuts down when trying to change maps.

**Update #2**: I created a Windows 10 Home virtual machine (on a Windows 10 Home host) using Virtualbox with 4 GB of RAM and two virtual CPUs. The same behavior is occurring (dedicated server crashes during a map change).

Comment: While I don't think this is the problem, I have to ask it just to make sure... are there any mvm maps in the `mapcycle.txt`?

Comment: @Powerlord thanks, I added my mapcycle.txt above.

Comment: @Powerlord out of curiosity, I reduced mapcycle.txt down to just koth_sawmill and koth_nucleus but the server still crashed during a map change.

Answer (score 1):

### Sounds like a RAM issue

Yes, TF2 idles around the 450 MB mark, but if the issue *only* occurs during map change, then chances are it's spiking way higher than 450 MB attempting to load all the new files for the new map, causing the error above.

As a test (and stop-gap solution), you can try increasing the page file size in Windows. A page file (also known as a swap file, or virtual memory) is a space on the hard drive that Windows will move stuff to when RAM is running low.

It's generally very slow when compared to using actual RAM, so I wouldn't recommend this as a long-term solution (especially if you want this server to eventually be hosted online), but it should stop TF2 from crashing and confirm this was the issue.

---

To increase the page file size, in Windows 10/11:

- Hit Start and type "Advanced System", you should see *"View Advanced System Settings."* Click on it.
- In System Properties, under the '*Advanced*' tab, click the '*Settings*' button under the 'Performance' box.
- In the new window that opens, under the 'Advanced' tab, click the '*Change button under the 'Virtual memory' box
- Uncheck *'Automatically manage paging file size for all drives'*
- Highlight your Windows system drive and select '*Custom size*'
- Change the Initial size value and the Maximum size value to a higher value. Note the current settings are shown below in MB.
- Click Set, then Apply/OK all the way back out.

---

Then, you should boot up TF2 and see what happens during a match change. If this fixes the issue, you can then look at purchasing more RAM for the system.